# Swift how to reload tableview after editActionsForRowAtIndexPath called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to update my tableview cells after an action is called in the editactionsForRowAtIndexPath function.

I've tried calling self.tableView.reloadData from the action handler, from the viewwillappear function and several other areas but it never reloads after the action is called.

What happens is a user swipes left and then they click the Confirm button which confirms an appointment and updates a value in the database.

The object is to have the function finish updating the value and then update the table by reloading so that in the cellforRowAtIndex can recycle through and color each cell a different color according to the values in the database.

But nothing seems to work.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]  {

    //confirm appointment
    let confirm_action = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Confirm", handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        self.index_number = indexPath.row

        let confirm_menu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Which request?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let number_1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Choice 1", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: self.confirm1)

        let number_2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Choice 2", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: self.confirm2)

        let number_3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Choice 3", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: self.confirm3)

        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

        confirm_menu.addAction(number_1)
        confirm_menu.addAction(number_2)
        confirm_menu.addAction(number_3)
        confirm_menu.addAction(cancel)

        self.presentViewController(confirm_menu, animated: true, completion: nil)
   self.tableView.reloadData()
        })

 return [confirm_action]
 }


//confirm choice1
func confirm1(alertAction: UIAlertAction!) -> Void {
    tableView.sectionIndexColor = UIColor.greenColor()


    //Update database entry to confirmed
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Schedule")

    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(object_ids[index_number]){
        (Schedule: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        //successfully loaded schedule request
        if(error == nil && Schedule != nil) {
            Schedule!["confirmed"] = "yes1"
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                Schedule!.saveInBackground()
            }
        }
    }

    //update table
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    index_number = 0
}


 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("schedules", forIndexPath: indexPath)


  //load cell text depending on confirmed or not
    if(confirmed_status[indexPath.row] == "yes1"){
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(users_names[indexPath.row]) \nPAID: \(paid_status[indexPath.row]) \nConfirmed for: \(location1) on \(date1)"
        cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        cell.editingStyle
    }
 else{

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(users_names[indexPath.row]) \nPAID: \(paid_status[indexPath.row]) \n#1 \(location1) on \(date1) \n#2 \(location2) on \(date2) \n#3 \(location3) on \(date3)"
    }


    //To enable word wrap for long titles
    cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0


    return cell
}
```